# syntax error, unexpected token "if" , how do i chain php script?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a directory made, after which a file is uploaded, the code looks a bit like this:

```
    login($inputs ['email'], $inputs ['password']) &&
      mkdir('file/file/'.$_SESSION['user_id'].'/Profile', 0777, true) &&
      logout() &&
(if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
  echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
  echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
})
```

However, if i use this snippit, i get the error code "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "if"", if i replace the "&&" with a semi-colon, the upload script will not execute! How do i make this work?

Comment: "*if i replace the "&&" with a semi-colon*" *Which* `&&` are you referring to? There are multiple. "*the upload script will not execute!*" What happens, instead? What errors are you seeing in your interface and in your server logs? [ask]

Comment: I was referring to the '&&' after 'logout()'. If i replace this with a semicolon, the error disappears, but the file that is supposed to be uploaded is not uploaded. If i remove the script starting from 'login' tot 'logout() &&', the file is uploaded

Comment: We really cannot help you very much unless you're able to modify your code such that it meets the standards of being a [mre], in accordance with [ask]; right now it's extremely convoluted what you're trying to do, what these methods in question actually *return*, and what specifically you've uncovered in your debugging to this point.

Comment: I'm not sure where the idea of "chaining" has come from, but what you've got here looks like a script that should just execute procedurally. Call `login`, then `mkdir`, then `logout`, and then run the conditional logic. The error in the title is appearing because you can't put an `if` statement in the middle of another conditional, but I think it'll make debugging this a lot easier if you just call one thing at a time, and check the result of each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided doesn't seem to be complete, but to get the question answered: You don't have to write "if" inside another "if" condition.

```
// this
if (condition1 == true) {
  if (condition2 == true) {}
}
// is the same as
if (condition1 == true && condition2 == true) {}
```

So the following is not needed and will most likely end in some kind of parsing error.

```
// the second "if" is not valid, you can keep the (), though
if ((condition1 == true) && if(condition2 == true)) {}
```

In order to clean this up you can of course nest these statements in functions, as you did with logout() and call these functions and chain them with && or || operators.

```
function folderIsCreated() {
  return mkdir(...);
}
// function 2...
if (folderIsCreated() && function2() && function3()) {}
```

Long story short for your code: Remove the if inside the if.

Comment: This helped me out! thanks a million,